# Google-maps-react: Value of props passed by parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I was making a small project using react with google map and I used [google-maps-react library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react).

The problem occurs whenever I get data from the server and extract the latitude and longitude information and pass those to the child component which is `HandleGoogleMap` as `props`, and set those as `initialCenter`, the map renders a location with `latitude:0` and `longitude:0` .

However, when I change the `initialCenter` value as just numbers, it renders the location correctly. But, I also logged the latitude and longitude props to be sure than those are numbers. Here is the code:

```
const HandleGoogleMap = props => {
  const { lat, lng } = props;

  // lat contains information of latitude
  // lng contains infromation of longitude

  console.log(lat);
  console.log(lng);

  return (
    <Map
      google={props.google}
      // when I change the value of lat and lng properties as numbers, it renders correctly 
      //but when I set values as props that the component passed by parent component, 
      //map renders lat: 0, lng:0 location
      initialCenter={{ lat: lat, lng: lng }}
      zoom={12}
    />
  );
};

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: "141423124123123123"
})(HandleGoogleMap);
```

Comment: Could it be a type issue. What is the console output of lat/lng ?

Comment: I added a solution please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the async nature of fetching the lat/lng from the api.
You are using initialCenter with these values which might be the issue.

> initalCenter: Takes an object containing latitude and longitude
>   coordinates. Sets the maps center upon loading.
>
> center: Takes an object containing latitude and longitude coordinates.
>   Use this if you want to re-render the map after the initial render.

Use the "center" property instead for the data coming from the api as the action is async and you will need to re-render the map once the data is received

```
<Map
  google={props.google}
  center={{ lat: lat, lng: lng }}
  zoom={12}
/>
```

Comment: yes, I should have thought of async nature of fetching data. Solved it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the props are not loaded this is how it works. use `props.loaded` and then `google={props.google}` as this snipped:

```
const HandleGoogleMap = props => {
  if (!props.loaded) return <div>Loading...</div>;


  return (
    <Map
      google={props.google}
      // when I change the value of lat and lng properties as numbers, it renders correctly 
      //but when I set values as props that the component passed by parent component, 
      google={props.google}
      zoom={12}
    />
  );
};

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: "141423124123123123"
})(HandleGoogleMap);
```